# Insert through parallel thread of dataframe in Cassandra

Tags: apache-spark, cassandra, apache-spark-sql, datastax-enterprise, spark-cassandra-connector

I have following code :-

```
collection.foreachRDD(rdd =>
  {
    if (!rdd.partitions.isEmpty) {
      println("RDD collected")
      try {
        val dfs = rdd.toDF()
 dfs.write.format("org.apache.spark.sql.cassandra").options(Map("table" -> "table", "keyspace" -> "db", "cluster" -> "Test Cluster"))
          .mode(SaveMode.Append).save()
      } catch {
        case e: Exception => e.printStackTrace
      }
      println("Written to cassandra")
    } else {
      println("blank rdd")
    }
  })
```

Now, I'm looking for a solution where I can write to Cassandra in parallel using thread or whatever because my write is very very slow it is going at around 2000-2200 per second. Thanks,

Comment: There is nothing wrong with this code.

Comment: @user8371915 - I want to parallel write in Cassandra but I think my code sequentially writes in db. So wanted to use some thread concept where I can consume and insert in db parrellely

Comment: As written, it distributes writes, using standard Spark workflow. It is not sequential.

Comment: Still If I use threading concept will it increase my insert speed ?